# Intuitive explanation of gravitational force being greater than normal force on a rotating planet?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, centrifugal-force

It makes sense to me mathematically that an object resting on a rotating planet would go along with it and have a lower normal force because acceleration should point to the center of rotation. But not intuitively...

Here is another source of my confusion:
Let's say that the planet has no friction. If we put an object on a surface, the object would be stationary in our frame of reference (inertial). But if we then added friction, our object would start going in circles...
How does friction, which is perpendicular to normal and gravitational forces, affect normal force? Does the object on the micro level jump up and down constantly since friction would "launch" it from the surface?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the root of your confusion is you think static friction is relied upon for an object to move with (and not slip on) the surface of the planet as it rotates. If that's the case, your thinking is incorrect.

If the planet is rotating at constant angular velocity there would be no tangential force acting on (and thus no tangential acceleration of) the object for friction to oppose.  An object sitting on a frictionless surface here on Earth would not be sliding on that surface (think of an object on ice).

Hope this helps.

Comment: There has been a misunderstanding. I meant to say that we are putting an object on a frictionless surface from an inertial frame of reference. A planet would spin under an object because there is no force that would influence the motion of an object, right?

Comment: @Human what exactly do you mean by “spin under the object “?

Comment: In our frame of reference, after we placed an object on a frictionless planet, the object would remain still in our frame of reference because, as said, there is no force that would act on it to make it go in circles. So essentially, the planet is spinning under the object.

Comment: What is “our frame of reference “?

Comment: Our frame of reference is inertial, away from planet.

Comment: The object will not remain still whilst the planet moves under it. Why doesn’t an ice skater remain still and the ice move under the skater?

Comment: Why not? What force would make that object move? Ice skater won't move because he already had angular velocity before he went on ice. And of course, angular velocity of Earth is unnoticeable. Am I not right?

Comment: @Human I’m sorry but now I have no idea what you are asking about. So I’m signing off. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In Newtonian mechanics, the net force equals mass times acceleration in an inertial frame. In the case: $F_g - N = \omega^2R \implies N = F_g - \omega^2R$.

If we could manage to launch an disk westward over the equator, over a frictionless lane, with a velocity so that the fixed stars were really fixed in its frame, $\omega = 0$ and the normal force would reach the maximum.

> How does friction, which is perpendicular to normal and gravitational
> forces, affect normal force?

It is not friction that affects normal force, but the angular velocity with respect to the stars. Friction is only a practical way to get a specific $\omega$, that of the rotation of the planet.

Comment: This helped a bit, but... it still doesn't make intuitive sense to me how gravitational force is greater than normal force when all my life I was thought that they are equal. What happens on the "micro level" that prevents objects from acting upon surfaces as much as gravitation can pull them?

Comment: Well. For real problems in the Earth, the downward force that equals Normal force is taken as local gravity.

Answer (score 0):

For an object to be resting on the surface of a rotating planet then it must be moving with the same velocity as the surface at all times. A given point on the surface moves in a circular path, meaning the object must be constantly accelerated so that it does too. Consider watching the planet from outer space in an inertial reference frame, and let's say the object is on the equator of a planet with radius $R$ which is rotating with angular velocity $\omega$ in the $xy$ plane. The circular path followed by a point on the equator is
$$\mathbf x(t) = R(\cos\omega t, \sin\omega t) = R\hat{\mathbf r}$$
which has velocity
$$\dot{\mathbf x}(t) = R\omega(-\sin\omega t, \cos\omega t) = R\omega\hat \phi$$
The acceleration which the object must experience to maintain this circular path is therefore
$$\ddot{\mathbf x}(t) = -R\omega^2(\cos\omega t, \sin\omega t) = -R\omega^2\hat{\mathbf r}$$
which points *towards* the center of the planet. This is called the *centripetal acceleration* $\mathbf a_{cp}$ and is the acceleration required to make the object move in a circle with a radius of *exactly* $R$ around the planet. Any less acceleration and the object which started on the surface would orbit the planet along an ellipse. Any more acceleration and the object is pulled into the surface, and in this case the normal force of the solid ground acts to cancel out this excess. Therefore the first part of the force of gravity goes towards keeping the object on the surface, and whatever is leftover is opposed by the normal force.
$$\mathbf F_g + \mathbf F_n = m\mathbf a_{cp} = -mR\omega^2\hat{\mathbf r}$$
From the inertial frame in outer space the object is clearly accelerating, but in a reference frame on the surface of the planet (which we often use on earth) the object is not moving meaning $\mathbf F_{net} = 0$, so it seems like there is another force working with the normal force to cancel out gravity. This is the fictitious *centrifugal force* $\mathbf F_{cf}$ associated with rotating reference frames which allows Newton's 2nd law to stay the same:
$$\mathbf F_{net} = \mathbf F_g + \mathbf F_n + \mathbf F_{cf} = 0$$
But really from the inertial frame we know this isn't a force but rather the centripetal acceleration associated with keeping the object on the circular path of the surface:
$$\mathbf F_{cf}  = -m\mathbf a_{cp}$$
Either way, this is the source of the difference between the gravitational force and the normal force
$$|F_g| - |F_n| = mR\omega^2$$

Comment: There has been a misunderstanding. I meant to say that we are putting an object on a frictionless surface from an inertial frame of reference. A planet would spin under an object because there is no force that would influence the motion of an object, right?

Comment: @Human That's right if the object was originally at rest wrt. the inertial frame, and there will be no centrifugal force.  In this case the addition of friction will cause the object to accelerate tangent to the surface until it's moving at the same speed as the surface. The important distinction to make is that it's not the frictional force which causes the centrifugal force, its the tangential velocity. In a case where the object is moving at *any* speed greater than 0 along the surface in the inertial frame, there will be a centrifugal force regardless of if the surface has friction or not.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the gravitational force is greater than the normal force due to tangential velocity, which (on a micro level) "doesn't allow" the body to press the surface with full weight because the velocity vector is pointed tangentially of the surface?